# ListBox Selected Items in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListBox` in WPF and it has `CheckBox` items inside. I'm splitting the checked checkboxes with the following code in XAML codebehind.

```csharp
StringBuilder sbMonths = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbMonthNames = new StringBuilder();

string months;
string monthNames;

foreach (var item in ListBox.Items)
{
    if (item is CheckBox)
    {
        var chk = item as CheckBox;

        if ((bool)chk.IsChecked)
        {
            sbMonths.Append(chk.Tag);
            sbMonths.Append(',');

            sbMonthNames.Append(chk.Content.ToString());
            sbMonthNames.Append('-');
        }
    }

}

months = sbMonths.ToString();
monthNames = sbMonthNames.ToString();
int lastIndexOfMonths = months.LastIndexOf(',');
int lastIndexOfMonthNames = monthNames.LastIndexOf('-');

if (lastIndexOfMonths > -1)
{
    months = months.Remove(lastIndexOfMonths);
    monthNames = monthNames.Remove(lastIndexOfMonthNames);
    .... I do more here
}
```

The thing is that I have no idea how to do this using MVVM. Would you provide some solutions?

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="149" Margin="23,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="-- Ay Seçiniz --"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Ocak" Tag="1"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Şubat" Tag="2"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Mart" Tag="3"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Nisan" Tag="4"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Mayıs" Tag="5"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Haziran" Tag="6"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Temmuz" Tag="7"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Ağustos" Tag="8"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Eylül" Tag="9"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Ekim" Tag="10"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Kasım" Tag="11"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Aralık" Tag="12"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=using+checkbox+in+listbox+in+wpf+mvvm

Comment: @Kix DuckDuckGo? Damn straight. Nobody can know that we're searching for how to use a checkbox in a listbox in WPF MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Following Code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Months}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="{Binding MonthName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Printing;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MonthViewModel> Months { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Months = new ObservableCollection<MonthViewModel>();

            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Ocak", MonthNumber = 1 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Şubat", MonthNumber = 2 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Mart", MonthNumber = 3 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Nisan", MonthNumber = 4 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Mayıs", MonthNumber = 5 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Haziran", MonthNumber = 6 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Temmuz", MonthNumber = 7 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Ağustos", MonthNumber = 8 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Eylül", MonthNumber = 9 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Ekim", MonthNumber = 10 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Kasım", MonthNumber = 11 });
            this.Months.Add(new MonthViewModel() { MonthName = "Aralık", MonthNumber = 12 });
        }
    }

    public class MonthViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string _monthName;
        public string MonthName
        {
            get { return _monthName; }
            set
            {
                if (_monthName != value)
                {
                    _monthName = value;
                    this.NotifyOnPropertyChange(() => this.MonthName);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    this.NotifyOnPropertyChange(() => this.IsSelected);
                }
            }
        }

        private int _monthNumber;
        public int MonthNumber
        {
            get { return _monthNumber; }
            set
            {
                if (_monthNumber != value)
                {
                    _monthNumber = value;
                    this.NotifyOnPropertyChange(() => this.MonthNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyOnPropertyChange(Expression<Func<object>> expression)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                if (expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Value must be a lamda expression", "expression");

                var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

                if (body == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should have a Body of type MemberExpression");
                }

                string propertyName = body.Member.Name;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Using above code at any point of time in `ViewModel`, you will be able to get the selected items from collection `Months` and you can apply your code as you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you would do this using MVVM.

First, create a Model (**M**VVM) for your months.

```
public class Month
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Index {get;set;} // or whatever else you need
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
}
```

Now, you want to expose those in your ViewModel (MV**VM**) both as a collection of all months.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    // init this in your ctor
    public ObservableCollection<Month> Months {get;private set;}
    // snip
```

And then bind to them in your View (M**V**VM)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Months}"> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

That's how MVVM *works*.

Comment: That's true. This is not MVVM. But I need to do it in MVVM ;) That's why I asked. 

So, I should create 12 Months individually like month1, month2. Then I will add to Months observable collection. Is that all ?

Comment: @Samet well, there ya go!  A simple MVVM implementation.  You'll have to figure out what triggers your date manipulation code and translate that into a MVVM paradigm equivalent...